# My paper/page size stopped working once I added speech bubbles to my document

Tags: environments, xparse

So I'm working on a project which is supposed to be in A5. I have a template for this kind of document and it has always worked just fine. This is the code I usually use:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}

 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 bottom=25mm
 }



  

\setlength{\parskip}{0.7em}



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{}
\chapter*{Title}
\vspace*{\fill}
\small Author
\chapter*{I}
\pagenumbering{arabic}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper dapibus semper. Donec eros erat, placerat eu molestie et, bibendum sed magna. Aliquam congue massa magna. Fusce id tempor libero. Proin pulvinar lorem orci, pretium tincidunt sapien bibendum et. In justo ex, facilisis non enim iaculis, finibus tincidunt eros. Nulla hendrerit magna orci. Sed et sem eu est consectetur ullamcorper et eget urna. Suspendisse eros lacus, placerat eu lacus id, congue feugiat tellus. Nunc massa lectus, vulputate sed accumsan nec, placerat in risus. Phasellus in ullamcorper mauris. Sed porttitor enim diam, nec vulputate sem congue non. Nunc sed ullamcorper erat.

Praesent lorem turpis, lacinia pulvinar nulla eget, tincidunt efficitur ante. Vestibulum vitae semper sapien. Maecenas finibus ut mi eu cursus. Mauris ac mauris sed nibh efficitur commodo ut ultrices neque. Integer facilisis gravida urna nec sollicitudin. Donec fringilla fringilla turpis, vitae tincidunt lacus scelerisque et. Mauris non ipsum vitae ex eleifend commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras blandit blandit elementum. Nam ac tempus diam. Integer leo quam, pulvinar ut porttitor in, pretium nec sapien. Proin rhoncus lorem nec sodales commodo. Morbi maximus porttitor ex, sed viverra lorem vehicula et. Pellentesque malesuada urna quis nisi tincidunt interdum. Sed non neque vitae ante tincidunt lobortis.

\end{document}
```

Now I added this code in the middle in order to be able to use speech bubbles, but that damaged the formatting. Now the entire text is halfway to the left. Either that or the page size is no longer A5.

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{geometry}
\begin{comment}

\end{comment}

 \geometry{
 a5paper,
 left=25mm,
 top=25mm,
 right=25mm,
 bottom=25mm
 }



  

\setlength{\parskip}{0.7em}

\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{varwidth}
\usepackage{environ}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{emoji}

\newlength{\bubblesep}
\newlength{\bubblewidth}
\setlength{\bubblesep}{2pt}
\AtBeginDocument{\setlength{\bubblewidth}{.75\textwidth}}
\definecolor{bubblereceive}{RGB}{100,200,200}
\definecolor{bubblesend}{RGB}{241,240,240}

\newcommand{\bubble}[4]{%
  \tcbox[
    on line,
    arc=4.5mm,
    colback=#1,
    colframe=#1,
    #2,
  ]{\color{#3}\begin{varwidth}{\bubblewidth}#4\end{varwidth}}%
}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
\tl_new:N \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl

\NewEnviron{rightbubbles}
 {
  \begin{flushright}
  \sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblesend}{rounded~corners}{black}{\BODY}\par
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblesend}{sharp~corners=southeast}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}
    \par\nointerlineskip
    \addvspace{\bubblesep}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblesend}{sharp~corners=east}{black}{##1}
      \par\nointerlineskip
      \addvspace{\bubblesep}
     }
    \bubble{bubblesend}{sharp~corners=northeast}{black}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}
    \par
   }
   \end{flushright}
 }
\NewEnviron{leftbubbles}
 {
  \begin{flushleft}
  \sffamily
  \seq_set_split:NnV \l__ooker_bubbles_seq { \par } \BODY
  \int_compare:nTF { \seq_count:N \l__ooker_bubbles_seq < 2 }
   {
    \bubble{bubblereceive}{rounded~corners}{white}{\BODY}\par
   }
   {
    \seq_pop_left:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl
    \seq_pop_right:NN \l__ooker_bubbles_seq \l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl
    \bubble{bubblereceive}{sharp~corners=southwest}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_first_tl}
    \par\nointerlineskip
    \addvspace{\bubblesep}
    \seq_map_inline:Nn \l__ooker_bubbles_seq
     {
      \bubble{bubblereceive}{sharp~corners=west}{white}{##1}
      \par\nointerlineskip
      \addvspace{\bubblesep}
     }
    \bubble{bubblereceive}{sharp~corners=northwest}{white}{\l__ooker_bubbles_last_tl}\par
   }
  \end{flushleft}
 }
\ExplSyntaxOff



\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{gobble}
\chapter*{}
\chapter*{Title}
\vspace*{\fill}
\small Author
\chapter*{I}
\pagenumbering{arabic}
Sample.

\begin{rightbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{rightbubbles}
\begin{rightbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{rightbubbles}
\begin{rightbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{rightbubbles}
\begin{leftbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{leftbubbles}
\begin{rightbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{rightbubbles}

\begin{leftbubbles}
Speech bubble
\end{leftbubbles}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc ullamcorper dapibus semper. Donec eros erat, placerat eu molestie et, bibendum sed magna. Aliquam congue massa magna. Fusce id tempor libero. Proin pulvinar lorem orci, pretium tincidunt sapien bibendum et. In justo ex, facilisis non enim iaculis, finibus tincidunt eros. Nulla hendrerit magna orci. Sed et sem eu est consectetur ullamcorper et eget urna. Suspendisse eros lacus, placerat eu lacus id, congue feugiat tellus. Nunc massa lectus, vulputate sed accumsan nec, placerat in risus. Phasellus in ullamcorper mauris. Sed porttitor enim diam, nec vulputate sem congue non. Nunc sed ullamcorper erat.

Praesent lorem turpis, lacinia pulvinar nulla eget, tincidunt efficitur ante. Vestibulum vitae semper sapien. Maecenas finibus ut mi eu cursus. Mauris ac mauris sed nibh efficitur commodo ut ultrices neque. Integer facilisis gravida urna nec sollicitudin. Donec fringilla fringilla turpis, vitae tincidunt lacus scelerisque et. Mauris non ipsum vitae ex eleifend commodo. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Cras blandit blandit elementum. Nam ac tempus diam. Integer leo quam, pulvinar ut porttitor in, pretium nec sapien. Proin rhoncus lorem nec sodales commodo. Morbi maximus porttitor ex, sed viverra lorem vehicula et. Pellentesque malesuada urna quis nisi tincidunt interdum. Sed non neque vitae ante tincidunt lobortis.

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok so after like 2 hours and trial and error I found out I simply had to switch
this

```
\documentclass{memoir}
```

with this

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{memoir}
```

and it started working again. It's just odd because I didn't have to include this bit before and it worked when I didn't have the speech bubble code.

Comment: the problem is that geometry doesn't set \stockwidth and so graphicx (which is loaded by tcolorbox) picks up the default from memoir. With memoir it is normally better to set the papersize with the memoir commands.